# SQL replace leading and trailing new line characters

Tags: mysql

I am trying to replace leading and trailing new line chars from a string.

`trim(field)` --> Doesn't remove new line chars

`REPLACE(field,'\n','')` --> remove new line char in all the places, but I want only the leading or the trailing new line character.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify what to remove:

```
trim('\n' from field)
```